# TimeStamp Column Auto Update Upon Insert and Modification

Tags: sql-server

I have been assigned with a task that is update Timestamp column of a table upon each insert or modification of table  data. As per my kowledge this can posssible in case of inserts using default getdate() for the column but NOT modification without trigger.

I am looking for help on a mechanism to update timestamp column upon modification of table data without trigger, of course if possible in SQL Server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of automated features you can use to accomplish this, without using **Triggers**:

1. [**Temporal Tables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) - System versioned copies of the user defined tables that track changes.
2. [**Change Tracking**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Automated tracking of changes for your user defined tables.
3. [**Change Data Capture**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Keeps track of DML changes to the specified user defined tables.
4. [**Audit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) - Automatically tracks a multitude of actions at the server level.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you mean the deprecated datatype timestamp now replaced by rowversion ?

In which case you only have to add a column of that datatype - the rest is self managing.
i.e. If the row is updated the value of the rowversion (aka timestamp) is updated too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Good thought. Just want to emphasize to @SQLHoncho the warning from those docs, should he decide to use the `timestamp` column: "*The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.*" So please use at your own risk.

Comment: On the other hand, the meta-data doesn't reflect that you specified the new and "better" name rowversion when you created the table. Script out that table (generate CREATE TABLE) and you'll get timestamp instead of rowversion even if you specified rowversion in the CREATE TABLE command initially. Based on that, the warning cannot be taken seriously, IMO. (As for this thread, I strongly feel that a datetime is desired, based on phrasing in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

For an insert you can use a **default constraint**, as you pointed.

For an update you have to use a trigger or modify the query or proceure that is doing the update.

Eventually you can use **temporal table** to track changes in records but that seems like a cannon to kill an ant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable contribution.